# Log4Net Output File Directory - ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, log4net

I am new to `log4net` and I am just trying to get familiar with it in a console line app.  Firstly I noticed from the few tutorials that the general configuration differs slightly, so it maybe the case that I have not got things setup properly.

The console printed fine, but the tutorial I was following placed the file in the same directory of the console app.  I found with mine I had to give it the explicit path to my project to work.

Here is my Program.cs

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    XmlDocument log4netConfig = new XmlDocument();
    log4netConfig.Load(File.OpenRead("log4net.config"));

    var repo = LogManager.CreateRepository(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly(), typeof(log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy));

    XmlConfigurator.Configure(repo, log4netConfig["log4net"]);

    var logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program));

    logger.Error("Hello, World!");
}
```

Here is my config

```
<log4net>
  
  <root>
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
    <appender-ref ref="file" />
  </root>
  
  <appender name="console" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date %level %logger - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  
  <appender name="file" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="c:\users\dpg\developer\TestLogging\TestLog4Net\loggingfun.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
    <maximumFileSize value="25MB" />
    <lockingmodel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  
</log4net>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use relative path for work folder

```
<file value="ErrorLog.txt"/>
```

for saving it to windows location such as LOCALAPPDATA

```
<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="${LOCALAPPDATA}\Temp\Log\App.log" />
```

Comment: Ah right I should of mentioned I'm on Windows, thus the relative path doesn't work.  So should it be if I want it in my project directory?

Comment: Ive even created a folder called `Logs` and it still doesn't work `Logs\loggingfun.log` and it still wont work

Comment: It can be permission isssue. Give that folder  full permission for everyone. It can help

Comment: Dont think its permissions as after some inspection some of my logs have ended up in the build directory so something fishy is going on.  E.g. `Project\bin\Debug\aspcoreapp3.1\loggingfun.log`

Comment: The problem is that everything ends in the build directory, even if you use an absolute path

Answer (score 0):

if using .NET core, and an environment variable like this:

```
<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="${LOCALAPPDATA}\Temp\Log\App.log" />
```

the log file will end in App/bin/debug/${LOCALAPPDATA}\Temp\Log\App.log

I found a way to solve this problem, by using a GlobalContext property.

**In code:**

```
log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["LocalAppData"] = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("LOCALAPPDATA");
var repository = LogManager.GetRepository(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly());
XmlConfigurator.Configure(repository, new FileInfo("App.config"));
```

**In App.config**

```
<appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <param name="StaticLogFileName" value="true" />
      <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="%property{LocalAppData}\Temp\Log\App.log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <encoding value="utf-8" />
      <rollingStyle value="Date" />
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%appdomain] [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline%exception%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
```

Answer (score 0):

Those who are looking to set the file path to Project root dicrectory Path can refer below code. I have implemented this in .NET 5 API Project

Changes for Log4net.config file. Remember `type="log4net.Util.PatternString"` this line is very important

```
<appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="%property{LoggerFilePath}\Logs\server.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <maximumFileSize value="100KB" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="2" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date %5level %logger.%method [%line] - MESSAGE: %message%newline %exception" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

Then, in `Program.cs` file

```
 public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureLogging((context,loggerBuilder) => 
            {
                log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["LoggerFilePath"] = context.HostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath;
                loggerBuilder.ClearProviders();
                loggerBuilder.AddLog4Net();
            })
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
```

Cheers !